# Why does my System.Net.FtpClient upload incomplete files when EnableThreadSafeDataConnections = false?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have a c# program that FTPs files to other servers. We recently got a client and they provided port 21 FTP credentials. I am using System.Net.FtpClient to upload files. If I leave EnableThreadSafeDataConnections = false, none of the files are uploaded in their entirety. The partial files that end up on the FTP site are always a multiple of 536 bytes in size.

If I let this property maintain it's default value of true, the files upload completely, but I get a `421 Too many connections (8) from this IP` error. This makes a bit of sense. I would prefer to not disconnect between files, because I'll be uploading 30 or 40 at a time somedays.

Here is some code:

```
            using (var ftpClient = new FtpClient())
            {
                foreach (string Key in LocalAndRemoteFilePathPairs.Keys)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(Key)) { continue; }

                    ftpClient.Host = Host;
                    ftpClient.Port = fd.PortNumber;
                    ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fd.LoginID, fd.LoginPassword);
                    ftpClient.EnableThreadSafeDataConnections = false; //do not open a new connection for each file
                    ftpClient.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.AutoPassive;

                    try
                    {
                        ftpClient.Connect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception conn_ex)
                    {
                        if ("No such host is known" == conn_ex.Message)
                        {
                            /**
                             * Do not fret when we can't connect the FTP,
                             * we might have 
                             * sabotaged the host name or credentials to
                             * specifically avoid uploading files to a 
                             * particular feed host (like localhost!)
                             */

                            Console.WriteLine("Ignoring this exception: [" + conn_ex.Message + "]");
                            return;
                        }
                        ThrowFTPConnectionException(fd, conn_ex);
                    }

                    //If the directory does not exist on the FTP, create it

                        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(LocalAndRemoteFilePathPairs[Key]);

                        if ("" != dir)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                //Does the directory exist?
                                ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory(dir);

                                /**
                                 * If the previous line didn't throw an 
                                 * exception, the directory exists. Now, 
                                 * get out of it and back where we were.
                                 */
                                foreach (string Level in dir.Split('/'))
                                {
                                    if ("" != Level)
                                    {
                                        ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory("..");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (FtpCommandException)
                            {
                                /** 
                                 * The directory to which we want to upload does not exist.
                                 * dir could actually contain a path of several directories.
                                 */

                                CreateDirectoryRecursively(ftpClient, dir);
                            }
                        }


                    //Actually upload the file
                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Key))
                    {
                        using (Stream ftpStream = ftpClient.OpenWrite(LocalAndRemoteFilePathPairs[Key]))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "Uploading " + (++counter).ToString() + "/" +
                                LocalAndRemoteFilePathPairs.Count.ToString() +
                                " " + LocalAndRemoteFilePathPairs[Key] +
                                " to " + Host
                            );

                            fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
                        }
                    }

                    ftpClient.Disconnect();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558561/system-net-ftpclient-openwrite-doesnt-upload-file-unless-i-insert-a-sleep-before  Using a similar Thread.Sleep() call increases my rate of success.